# Removing special characters from a string in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, pipe

Let's say I get a string with special characters and I want to use filter/pipe to change it. Also the first letter of each word should be uppercase.

For example `"@!₪ test stri&!ng₪"` will become `"Test String"`.

How can that be done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do with a pipe as follows,

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
@Pipe({
  name: 'specialPipe'
})
export class specialPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: string): string {
    let newVal = value.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '')
    return newVal.charAt(1).toUpperCase() + newVal.slice(2);
  }

}
```

**[DEMO STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tpkub4?file=src%2Fapp%2FspecialPipe.ts)**

Comment: thanks a lot what changes to do at the app.module to make that work?

Comment: you need to add that to the declarations, check the demo

Comment: just did now. thought the first letter is uppercase the other doesnt change to lower how can i do that?

Comment: it does check the sample

Comment: I just saw the update on sample. it changes all letters of all words to lowercase all but the first letter of first word. i want every word's first letter to be upper case. Right now I get Test string instead of Test String ...@Sajeetharan

Comment: check now it should be fine

Comment: please have a look

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regular expression, along with `replace` within your pipe to do so.

Firstly, use

```
str = str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "")
```

This will remove all non-alpha characters

You can then use

```
str = str.replace(/\b\w/g, (str) => str.toUpperCase())
```

This will replace any letter character that is next to a word boundary (such as a space) with the upper case version.

You can then chain it together, like so:

```js
let str = "@!₪ test stri&!ng₪";

str = str.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, "") // Remove non word characters
         .trim() // Remove trailing and leadings spaces
         .replace(/\b\w/g, (s) => s.toUpperCase()) // Make the first letter of each word upper case

console.log(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

use from the website: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/)

For example: 
You want split or remove custome string: '@!₪ test stri&!ng₪'
Type string in Test String